# What is the difference between using (components) and (extends with section & yield)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel, what is the difference between using:

1. components
2. extends with section & yield

I see that extends with section & yield do the same job of components.

Comment: Components are meant to be reusable and smaller in scope. If you go at it semantically, a page layout may extend a central layout and consist of various sections and each section can have multiple components in it. Components fit in a smaller scope if you use this sort of approach to writing your views. Generally speaking I would not replace extends and sections with components but I would use them alongside each other

Answer (score 0):

Components allow you an additional layer of abstraction to resolve the fragment of data it returns.  You can add an extra class that can do things like add data to a view, which is then returned.

If you don't need the additional layer of abstraction, then there's a good chance that @include is right for you.

An example would be a snippet for Google Analytics.  You can write it just as a blade file and include it.  What if you wanted to reuse it in multiple systems as part of your boilerplate in every project?  You can rewrite it every time, or you can take advantage of using the configuration.  You can get config variables inside of blade templates without a problem, but then you end up dealing with logic within the template.  There are plenty of arguments on if this is good practice.  My experience says to write it so that a front-end developer can do it without knowing the code behind the template.  That's why I'd prefer a component.  They know they have a variable for an Analytics ID and that's all they need.  They don't need to know where the configuration file is, how it's formatted, or anything, because you took care of it as a responsible developer.